# jOOQ + Spring : PSQLException: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, transactions, jooq

I'm developing a webapp which uses Spring and jOOQ.

Consider the following use case:

1. I open URL which renders result of the db query: `select * from contract_ref`, everything works ok.
2. I open URL which tries to run query which trigger Postgres error, i.e. `select * from users_ref` (table users_ref doesn't exist), and got error:

   `Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/astra] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: jOOQ; bad SQL grammar [select * from "users_ref"]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: отношение "users_ref" не существует`.
3. When I try to open page from step 1, I get the error `PSQLException: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`, but I see that webapp tries to execute statement from step 1.

It's seems for me that the situation is like Postgres didn't close transaction, but I do only `select` and so there's no any transaction required.

When I add `@Transactional` annotation for `ReferenceController.view` behaviour described above disappears.

Full log: http://pastebin.com/t3UmbeCy

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xmlns:bean="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <cache:annotation-driven/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.kerba"/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="localDbDataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
          class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>

    <bean:annotation-driven>
        <bean:message-converters>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
        </bean:message-converters>
    </bean:annotation-driven>


    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
        <property name="caches">
            <set>
                <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean">
                    <property name="name" value="user-page"/>
                </bean>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
        <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="requestContext"/>
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.lang.NullPointerException">exception</prop> <!-- map exception to view name -->
                <prop key="org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException">exception</prop> <!-- map exception to view name -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-common.xml</value>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-admin.xml</value>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-requests.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="preparerFactoryClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.SpringBeanPreparerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="liquibase" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">
        <property name="dropFirst" value="true"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="localDbDataSource"/>
        <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:db.astra.index.xml"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localDbDataSource"
          class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="${db.maxIdle}"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="${db.minIdle}"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="${db.maxActive}"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="${db.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis}"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="${db.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis}"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="${db.testWhileIdle}"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="${db.validationQuery}"/>
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="${db.removeAbandoned}"/>
        <property name="logAbandoned" value="${db.logAbandoned}"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="${db.initialSize}"/>
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionAwareDataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
        <constructor-arg ref="localDbDataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider" name="connectionProvider">
        <constructor-arg ref="transactionAwareDataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="exceptionTranslator"
          class="net.kerba.astra.exception.SpringExceptionTranslator"/>

    <bean class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration" name="jooqConfig">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="connectionProvider"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1">
            <null/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="2">
            <null/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="3">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteListenerProvider">
                    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="exceptionTranslator"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="4">
            <null/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="5">
            <value type="org.jooq.SQLDialect">POSTGRES</value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="6">
            <null/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="7">
            <null/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dsl" class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext">
        <constructor-arg ref="jooqConfig"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="patientDao" class="net.kerba.astra.jooq.tables.daos.PatientDao">
        <property name="configuration" ref="jooqConfig" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="patientStatusDao" class="net.kerba.astra.jooq.tables.daos.PatientStatusRefDao">
        <property name="configuration" ref="jooqConfig" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="requestUrgencyRefDao" class="net.kerba.astra.jooq.tables.daos.RequestUrgencyRefDao">
        <property name="configuration" ref="jooqConfig" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="divisionRefDao" class="net.kerba.astra.jooq.tables.daos.DivisionRefDao">
        <property name="configuration" ref="jooqConfig" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="requestStateRefDao" class="net.kerba.astra.jooq.tables.daos.RequestStateRefDao">
        <property name="configuration" ref="jooqConfig" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

ReferencesController:

```
package net.kerba.astra.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("references")
public class ReferencesController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReferencesController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ReferenceService referenceService;

    @Autowired
    private DSLContext dsl;

    private static final Map<String,Object> REFERENCES_CONFIG = loadReferencesList();

    private static Map<String,Object> loadReferencesList() {
        final InputStream resourceAsStream = ReferencesController.class.getResourceAsStream("ReferencesController.data.json");
        Objects.requireNonNull(resourceAsStream, "resourceAsStream must not be null");

        final InputStreamReader json;

        try {
            json = new InputStreamReader(resourceAsStream, "utf8");
            Objects.requireNonNull(json, "json must not be null");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: utf8", e);
        }

        final Map map = new Gson().fromJson(json, Map.class);
        Objects.requireNonNull(map, "map must not be null");

        SortedMap<String,Object> sortedMap = new TreeMap(new Comparator() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                String key1 = (String) o1;
                String key2 = (String) o2;

                if (key1 != null && key2 != null) {
                    return key1.compareTo(key2);
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
        sortedMap.putAll(map);

        return sortedMap;
    }

    /**
     * Индексная страница справочников
     * @param model
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("referencesConfig", REFERENCES_CONFIG);
        model.addAttribute("pageTitle", "Справочники");
        return "references.index";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "view/{referenceName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String view(Model model,@PathVariable("referenceName") String referenceName) {
        model.addAttribute("referencesConfig", REFERENCES_CONFIG);

        if (!REFERENCES_CONFIG.containsKey(referenceName)) {
            model.addAttribute("pageTitle", "Справочник не найден");
            model.addAttribute("message", "Справочник не найден!");
            return "error";
        } else {
            final Map currentRef = (Map) REFERENCES_CONFIG.get(referenceName);
            model.addAttribute("pageTitle", "Справочник: «" + currentRef.get("name") + "»");
            model.addAttribute("selectedReferenceConfig", currentRef);
            model.addAttribute("selectedReferenceConfigKey", referenceName);

            SelectQuery selectQuery = dsl.selectQuery();
            final String tableName = currentRef.get("tableName").toString();
            Objects.requireNonNull(tableName, "tableName must not be null");
            selectQuery.addFrom(DSL.tableByName(tableName));
            final Result result = selectQuery.fetch();

            logger.info("result: {}", result.intoMaps());
            model.addAttribute("referenceData", result.intoMaps());
            return "references.index";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Transactions* are **always** present with *Postgres*. There are various options to control them, such as *explicit transactions* (`BEGIN`-`END` blocks in pure *SQL*) versus *implicit transactions*, where they're not declared but implied.

There's also *autocommit*, where the transaction is ended for you automatically after each statement -- i.e. `COMMIT` if successful or `ROLLBACK` if not. This doesn't allow for multiple separate commands under the same transaction, however, which is often desirable.

*jOOQ* does not manage transactions at all, and defers to existing methods to manage them (*Spring* `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` in your case). Adding `@Transactional` defines for *Spring* the attributes of the transaction (you can do things like set the *isolation level*, among other things).

So if you are getting the expected behavior with that annotation in place, I think that's fine and to be expected, since, as I mentioned above, *Postgres* is always transactional. Without that annotation, Spring doesn't treat the interaction with *Postgres* as if it's transactional, even though at the *Postgres* level it is, and thus you get the behavior such as trying to do additional queries on an aborted transaction, resulting in an exception.